# MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline filter based on properties of child objects within array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

Given documents with the following structure:

```
{ 'id': 1, name: 'bob', type: 'foo', children: [{'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]}
{ 'id': 2, name: 'bob', type: 'foo' }
{ 'id': 3, name: 'bob', type: 'bar' }
{ 'id': 4, name: 'bob', type: 'foo', children: [{'id': 5}, {'id': 6}]}
{ 'id': 5, name: 'bob', type: 'foo' }
{ 'id': 6, name: 'bob', type: 'foo' }
```

How could I write an aggregate pipeline query to find all the documents where, if they have children, all the children are of type `foo` (and the parent is of type 'foo')?

Additional notes:

- `children` is an array of objects with a property referencing other documents in the same collection
- not all documents have children
- changing the document structure is not an option
- I've looked into $unwind and $lookup, but this results in many documents and I only want the parent document at the end of this.

Comment: Include the query you came up with and its result.

Comment: I don't have a working query, hence the question. The closest I've come is with a simple lookup but then getting the match to work against every nested document hasn't been successful. It is not clear to me if that's the correct approach or if something else will work better. Even if that works, I don't know if it's optimal or if there's a simpler approach. I just don't have the mongodb expertise.

Comment: Review http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ then add your query and results.

Comment: @D.SM Not to worry, I've added my own answer with the solution I've found. I hope it is useful to others in the future. Feel free to downvote, though. I still don't feel my myriad of failed iterations would have at all helped clarify the question, they would have instead made it substantially more convoluted and confusing. There's an infinite number of wrong ways to do something, and I attempted quite a few.

Answer (score 1):

After some additional toying with the aggregation pipeline API, here is one potential solution.

The steps are:

1. First `$match` based on the `type` criterion, to ensure only the parent documents with the appropriate `type` are used subsequently in the pipeline.
2. Perform a simple `$lookup` on the child documents. Although this doesn't appear to be explicitly documented, `$lookup` can use properties of nested objects in arrays with no difficulty.
3. Perform a final match on the resulting documents, making use of `$elemMatch` and some negation to achieve the desired effect.

Here's what that looks like using Robo3T (should be easily translated to other query clients):

*Note: In this particular case, `id` is just a placeholder for whatever the documents are being joined on, it is not the "official" `_id` mongo field*

```
db.getCollection('items').aggregate([
    { $match : { "type": "foo" } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "items",
            localField: "children.id",
            foreignField: "id",
            as: "items"
        }
    },
    {
        $match : { 
            "items": {
                $not: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        "type": { $ne: "foo" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

This will exclude documents 1 and 3, since 3 has a type of "bar" and 1 includes it.

This may not be an optimal solution, I have not tested it on large datasets. Also, the final match using `$elemMatch` is quite messy, so recommendations for improvements on that are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a solution. please take a look the query. solution checkup link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/cu7Mf8XZHDI

this query is similar to the question: [MongoDB (Mongoose) how to returning all document fields using $elemMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092265/mongodb-mongoose-how-to-returning-all-document-fields-using-elemmatch/69440509#69440509)

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  students: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$students",
      as: "student",
      cond: {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$$student.age",
              8
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              "$$student.age",
              15
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```